# Optimising the maximum value in a list in O(nlog(range of bounds)) time

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, combinatorics, greedy, minimization

Currently I got a problem in which we have two arrays say `x=[x1,x2,x3,...,xn]`
and array `y=[y1,y2,y3,...,yn]` and a value say k. Now I have to generate an array say `z=[z1,z2,z3,...,zn]` from k, such that `z1+z2+z3...+zn=k` . For different z generated what will be the minimum value of max of `[(x1-z1)*y1, (x2-z2)*y2, (x3-z3)*y3, ...., (xn-zn)*yn]`. i.e minimum value of maximum of `(x[i]-z[i])*y[i]` . For e.g. if `x=[2,3,4,1,6]` and `y=[3,5,2,7,3]` and k=4 than taking `z=[0,1,0,0,3]` gives array `[6,10,8,7,9]` for which maximum is `10` which is also minimum maximum.

 I designed an algorithm which computes it in `O(nlog(n)+k)` .Here if k will be very large than my algorithm will be inefficient. Can we do it in `O(n)` or `O(nlog(n))` .
My Current Algorithm is:

```
1. l=[] //initialize empty array
2. for i from 0 to n:
     l.append(x[i]*y[i],y[i])
3. Sort l in decreasing order of (x[i]*y[i])
4. while(m>0):
     num=l[0][0]-l[1][0] //take difference of two largest x[i]*y[i]
     t=(num/l[0][1])+1 //Choose appropriate number to subtract to minimize 
                         the maximum
     t=max(0,t)        // t must not be negative
     l[0][0]=l[0][0]-t*l[0][1]
     Put l[0] at correct position in sorted list l //Since value of 
                                                     l[0][0] has 
                                                     changed we will 
                                                     place it at 
                                                     correct position 
                                                     in already sorted  
                                                     l (using binary 
                                                     search)
     m=m-t
5.Print l[0][0] as the minimum maximum
```

Comment: Can you please share your current algorithm/s?

Comment: Yeah, I sure I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can calculate or estimate the lower and upper bound on your answer (which is minimum possible maximum value of your resulting array) then you can use binary search to solve this problem.

To binary search the answer we now need a predicate, let's call it p.

`p(val)` = `true` if there exists an array `z` such that the max value of `(xi-zi) * yi` is less than equal to `val` and `false` otherwise

To prove that binary search will work using this predicate we need to prove two things:

1. if `p(a) = true`
   then `p(b) = true` for all `b >= a`
2. if `p(a) = false`
   then `p(b) = false` for all `b <= a`

These two statements can be proved using the definition of the predicate.

To evaluate the predicate for a given value, try to estimate each `zi`:

1. if `xi * yi > val` then choose a minimum possible `zi` such that `xi*yi - zi*yi <= val`
2. otherwise choose maximum possible(in magnitude) `zi` such that `xi*yi - zi*yi <= val` is still true

Now, there will be three cases:

1. if sum of `zi` is `<k`, then you can can select any one positive `zi` and increase it to a point that sum of `zi` becomes `k`. You can see that increasing this `zi` won't effect the predicate value as maximum of `(xi-zi)*yi` would still be less than `k`. In this case predicate will be true.
2. if sum is exactly `k`, then again true.
3. if the sum is greater than `k` then the result is false. As in this case, no negative `zi` can be chosen and decreased more because its already at the maximum value allowed.

Now, its time for some code.

```
low = -100
high = 100 # these two are assumed values

x = [2, 3, 7, 1, 6]
y = [3, 5, 2, 7, 3]
k = 4

def p(val):
    sum_zi = 0  # sum of possible zi
    for idx in range(len(x)):
        if x[idx]*y[idx] > val:
            diff = x[idx]*y[idx] - val
            zi = (diff + y[idx] - 1) // y[idx]
            sum_zi += zi
        else:
            diff = x[idx]*y[idx] - val
            zi = diff // y[idx]
            sum_zi += zi
    return sum_zi <= k

while low < high:
    mid = (low + high)//2
    if p(mid):
        high = mid
    else:
        low = mid+1

print("Min possible max value", low)
# output = 10
```

Using this you can calculate your result in `nlog(range of bounds)`

Comment: If we can find maximum of x and y array and take high as max(x) * max(y) . Then this algorithm can be more generalised.

Comment: Yes. But to be more precise `high` would be `max(xi * yi)`.

Comment: prashantpiyush and @SachinSingh, does this algorithm work also if `x_i` and `y_i` can have a mix of negative and positive numbers?

Comment: Yes, this would work even if you have a mix of positives and negatives. You can see there is no assumption made about the numbers in the algorithm.

Comment: If we can have negative values of `z_i`, wouldn't this statement no longer be true? "If the sum of zi calculate till now is >k then the value of predicate is false."

Comment: Thanks @גלעדברקן for bringing my attention to this statement. This statement is actually false, not just for negative numbers but positives too. I'll be updating the answer, please give it a read and tell me if there is anything else wrong.